# ¿Cómo cargar un multiselect seleccionado para editaro/actualizar?

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

Ésto es lo que he intentado pero no los carga.

> *Clase y función*

```
class ProductData {
    public static $tablename = "estudiantes";

public function ProductData(){
    $this->nombres = "";
    $this->apellidos = "";
    $this->direccion = "";
    $this->telefono = "";
    $this->id_instrumento = "";
    $this->fecha_inscripcion = "NOW()";
    $this->nombre_pastor = "";
    $this->tel_pastor = "";
    $this->anio_escolar = "NOW()";
    $this->image = "";

}
public function update(){
    $sql = "update ".self::$tablename." set Nombres=\"$this->nombres\",Apellidos=\"$this->apellidos\",
    Direccion=\"$this->direccion\",Telefono=\"$this->telefono\",id_Instrumento=\"$this->id_instrumento\",
    id_Diplomado=\"$this->id_diplomado\",Nombre_pastor=\"$this->nombre_pastor\",Tel_pastor=\"$this->tel_pastor\" where id=$this->id";
    Executor::doit($sql);
}
}
```

> El POST

```
<?php

if(count($_POST)>0){
    $product = ProductData::getById($_POST["product_id"]);

$product->nombres = $_POST["nombres"];
$product->apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$product->direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$product->telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$product->id_instrumento = implode(",",$_POST["id_instrumento"]);
$product->id_diplomado = $_POST["id_diplomado"];
$product->nombre_pastor = $_POST["nombre_pastor"];
$product->tel_pastor = $_POST["tel_pastor"];

$product->user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$product->update();

if(isset($_FILES["image"])){
    $image = new Upload($_FILES["image"]);
    if($image->uploaded){
        $image->Process("storage/products/");
        if($image->processed){
            $product->image = $image->file_dst_name;
            $product->update_image();
        }
    }
}

setcookie("prdupd","true");
print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=editestudiante&id=$_POST[product_id]';</script>";
```

> El Formulario

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instrumentos*</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<?php 
    $instrumentos = InstrumentosData::getAllArray();

?>
  <select multiple name="id_instrumento[]"  class="form-control" required>
  <option value="" >-- NINGUNO --</option>
<?php foreach($instrumentos as $instrumento):?>
  <option value="<?php echo $instrumento->id;?>" <?php if($instrumento->id ==$product->id_Instrumento){ echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $instrumento->Nombre;?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La función ProductData no devuelve nada.

```
$product = ProductData::getById($_POST["product_id"]);
```

Aquí la tienes definida:

```
public function ProductData(){
    $this->nombres = "";
    $this->apellidos = "";
    $this->direccion = "";
    $this->telefono = "";
    $this->id_instrumento = "";
    $this->fecha_inscripcion = "NOW()";
    $this->nombre_pastor = "";
    $this->tel_pastor = "";
    $this->anio_escolar = "NOW()";
    $this->image = "";

}
```

Comment: por que la recomendación de mysqli?

Comment: @element ¿Por qué no?, Es una extensión muy buena además que se vería un poco más limpio el código.

Comment: a lo que voy es como sabes que no la esta usando? o que usa PDO?

Comment: @element touché

Comment: Si devuelve, porque en el formulario todos los datos los obtiene sin problema, e incluso si ese Multiselect lo paso a Select simple funciona, pero ya como Multiselect no. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Symfony como lo mencionas en la respuesta de Pada, no lo estas haciendo de la forma correcta, Primero debes crear una entidad usando doctrine, luego creas un FormClass

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'Product',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Product::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
    }
```

Y luego solo lo dibujas

```
{{ form_start(form) }} {{ form_widget(form) }} {{ form_end(form) }}
```

El solito obtiene toda la data para que la modifiques.